# cordova href "tel" not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am tring to make a phone call with cordova and I dont success.
I have the code:

```
<a class="button button-block button-positive" href="tel:+9720505050505" >
                    call
                </a>
```

and in config.xml:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
```

What I do wrong?

***ionic info:***

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1  : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms         : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework           : ionic1 1.3.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to install white list plugin `cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this code in your config.xml,

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

because your app need to go to external app of the mobile or navigator and this result worked for me.